# Open file one directory below

Tags: url-rewriting

I can't really explain or title this one so I'll use an example.

On my website I want `/img/image.jpg/1.jpg` to open `image.jpg` when opened but keep that URL. Basically I want that whatever is entered after `image.jpg/` doens't matter and it would always open image.jpg. Could it be done with .htaccess setting or would I need to do something more advanced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this can be done using .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^img/image.jpg/.*$ image.jpg
```

EDIT : 
To make image.jpg a variable too, you have to use brackets like this :

```
# This rule will match every URL img/nameofimage.jpg/randomcaracters and will redirect to nameofimage.jpg
RewriteRule ^img/([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.jpg)/.*$ $1
```